# Can we make Mathematica output the sequence of row operations it does when executing RowReduce[]?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Mathematica does row reduction with the function `RowReduce[]` but can we make it output the sequence of row operations it made. For example, something like this:

> [image]

Comment: If the linked threads do not suit your needs, please edit the question to explain why.